# Looping through unordered list to add and remove classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to iterate through an unordered list and loop through each list item (with the class of *ticker-item*) and temporarily append a class to it so that CSS can apply some transitions to it).

```
var a = [];
$(".ticker-item").each(function(index) {
  a[index] = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    a[index].addClass('current').delay(500).queue(function(next) {
      a[index].removeClass('current');
      next();
    });
  }, index * 500);
});
```

I've searched through various SO articles, and I'm confident that the function will add and remove the classes correctly, but it doesn't currently seem to be applying the li's?

And here is the HTML:

```
      <div class="ticker">
        <ul class="ticker-items">
            <li class="ticker-item">
                <a href="/categories/featured/summer-sale/1185">
                    <p><strong>Summer Sale</strong> Now more things at <strong>50% off!</strong></p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ticker-item">
                <a href="/about">
                    <p>Things for kids you'll  too. <strong>Our story</strong></p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ticker-item">
                <a href="/help/delivery-and-returns">
                    <p><strong>Free</strong> Delivery* &amp; <strong>Free</strong> Returns </p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are missing the class selector (a dot);  `$("ticker-item")` should be `$(".ticker-item")`

Comment: Typo, `$('ticker-item')` should be `$('.ticker-item')`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Sorry, typo fixed, but the issue remains. Do i need to add a . to current too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addClass` nor `removeClass` are using the queue by definition. So `jQuery#delay` will have no effect on these methods.

The solution is to execute both of them into queued callbacks in order for them to be pushed into the queue, like the following:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  $('#noqueue')
    .addClass('colored')
    .delay(2000)
    .removeClass('colored');
  
  $('#queue')
    .queue(function(next) {
      $(this).addClass('colored');
      next();
    })
    .delay(2000)
    .queue(function() { $(this).removeClass('colored'); });
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  transition: color .5s;
}

.colored {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="noqueue">no queue</div>
<div id="queue">with queue</div>
```

And I made a example below to chaining your animation.

Note that I didn't use `setTimeout` but I only used `jQuery#delay`, as I find that's cleaner.

Also, don't forget to dequeue your animations if you want to reexecute them without refreshing your page.

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {
  $('ul > li').each((i, li) => {
      $(li)
        .delay(500 * (i + 1))
        .queue(next => {
          $(li).addClass('colored');
          next();
        })
        .delay(750)
        .queue(() => ($(li).removeClass('colored'), $(li).dequeue()));
  });
});
```

```css
ul > li {
  transition: color 1s;
}

.colored {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<button>Color them!</button>
```

Comment: Great, that's working. Although it's not looping through as I'd expected? How do I get it to loop through this continually?

Answer (score 2):

You do not loop through elements with the class `ticker-item`, you loop through elements that are like this: `<ticker-item> ... </ticker-item>`

To change your loop you have to use the class-selecter:

```
$(".ticker-item").each
```

Comment: Fixed that typo, but still doesn't seem to work. Do I need to add a dot to the "addClass" function too?

Answer (score 0):

you are not accessing by class name,

change $("ticker-item").each to $(".ticker-item").each (class selector)